Need to calculate 24 hour average where NAs are considered 0
I'm trying to calculate a 24 hour average from hourly readings where NAs are not counted as part of the divisor and I'm successful in this calculation, but I'm also trying to calculate the 24 hour average from hourly readings where NAs are considered 0 and included in the divisor.
data <- data.frame(
   day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed"),
   hour_1 = c(4, 6, NA),
   hour_2 = c(4, 0, NA),
   hour_3 = c(4, 0, NA),
   hour_4 = c(5, 3, 0),
   hour_5 = c(4, 4, 1),
   hour_6 = c(NA, 2, 1),
   hour_7 = c(NA, 1, 1),
   hour_8 = c(NA, 3, NA),
   hour_9 = c(NA, 4, NA),
   hour_10 = c(NA, 5, 3),
   hour_11 = c(NA, 2, 1),
   hour_12 = c(NA, 0, 2),
   hour_13 = c(54, 3, 2),
   hour_14 = c(NA, 2, -1),
   hour_15 = c(NA, 4, -1),
   hour_16 = c(56, 5, 0),
   hour_17 = c(49, NA, 2),
   hour_18 = c(NA, 6, 2),
   hour_19 = c(1, 12, 2),
   hour_20 = c(47, NA, 6),
   hour_21 = c(NA, 7, 5),
   hour_22 = c(NA, 8, 7),
   hour_23 = c(102, 6, 5),
   hour_24 = c(NA, 9, 3))

I am able to calculate the average when NA's are removed using
data$average1 <- apply(data [,c("hour_1", "hour_2", "hour_3", "hour_4", "hour_5", "hour_6", "hour_7", "hour_8", "hour_9", "hour_10", "hour_11", "hour_12", "hour_13", "hour_14", "hour_15", "hour_16", "hour_17", "hour_18", "hour_19", "hour_20", "hour_21", "hour_22", "hour_23", "hour_24")], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

I then tried using  na.rm = FALSE to calculate the average where NAs are considered 0
data$average2 <- apply(data [,c("hour_1", "hour_2", "hour_3", "hour_4", "hour_5", "hour_6", "hour_7", "hour_8", "hour_9", "hour_10", "hour_11", "hour_12", "hour_13", "hour_14", "hour_15", "hour_16", "hour_17", "hour_18", "hour_19", "hour_20", "hour_21", "hour_22", "hour_23", "hour_24")], 1, mean, na.rm = FALSE)

This is just producing average values of NA though.
> print(data)
  day hour_1 hour_2 hour_3 hour_4 hour_5 hour_6 hour_7 hour_8 hour_9 hour_10 hour_11
1 Mon      4      4      4      5      4     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA
2 Tue      6      0      0      3      4      2      1      3      4       5       2
3 Wed     NA     NA     NA      0      1      1      1     NA     NA       3       1
  hour_12 hour_13 hour_14 hour_15 hour_16 hour_17 hour_18 hour_19 hour_20 hour_21 hour_22
1      NA      54      NA      NA      56      49      NA       1      47      NA      NA
2       0       3       2       4       5      NA       6      12      NA       7       8
3       2       2      -1      -1       0       2       2       2       6       5       7
  hour_23 hour_24  average1 average2
1     102      NA 30.000000       NA
2       6       9  4.181818       NA
3       5       3  2.157895       NA


Using lotus's recommendation I was able to calculate the average with NAs considered 0.
rowMeans(replace(data[-1], is.na(data[-1]), 0))


I suspect you will find your data easier to work with in general if you pivot it to long format:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data = data %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_prefix = 'hour_', -day, names_to = 'hour', values_to = 'reading')

   day   hour  reading
 1 Mon   1           4
 2 Mon   2           4
 3 Mon   3           4
 4 Mon   4           5
 5 Mon   5           4
 6 Mon   6          NA
 7 Mon   7          NA
 8 Mon   8          NA
 9 Mon   9          NA
10 Mon   10         NA

This way you won't run into situations where you have to reference every single "hour_" column to perform an operation. From there, finding the means can be done as follows:
data %>% 
  mutate(reading = case_when(is.na(reading) ~ 0, TRUE ~ reading)) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(reading))


Thanks Richard I agree long format is usually preferred! With the full dataset I'm working with and the data tidying I have to do it makes more sense to be in a wider format. Will definitely be using this for some other problems I'm working on though!
